# Stopping in app monthly subscription

Tags: applications, in-app-purchase

I downloaded an app called Vysor - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.vysor

I wanted to remove the ads so I purchased a monthly subscription - from their website. The ads got removed & it worked fine. Now I want to stop the monthly subscription after the first month is over. However, I see no option for this on the app itself to stop subscription.

In the playstore, my subscription doesn't show in "My subscriptions" - I have written to the email id given with the app and am waiting for a response. But other than that, what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from [a page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/110558071969009568835/posts/ZYU9dED8DPG) from the Vysor Google+ community:

> **Subscription Management, Cancellations, Invoices**
>
> Cancellation can be done any time. Just go into your account management and cancel the subscription. Instructions below.
>
> **Chrome Web Store Subscriptions**
>
> Vysor subscriptions purchased on the Chrome Store (Google Wallet) can be canceled in your Google Wallet bills section. If you cancel a subscription on the Chrome store, you will never be able to resubscribe with the Chrome store. Not even on a different plan. This is a bug with the Chrome store.

Answer (score 0):

This guide was commented but not posted as an answer..

To clarify for others, your answer is here [Vysor Google+ Billing and Licensing](https://plus.google.com/u/0/110558071969009568835/posts/ZYU9dED8DPG)